# Anomaly Detection Methods without using Threshold

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I have done anomaly detection using autoencoder with threshold.(data is time series data). So from my understanding, this threshold method cannot detect anomalies if they lie below the threshold, so does anyone have suggestion on detecting anomalies that will occur below threshold or any algorithms to improve on that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the existence of a threshold. That needs to be applied whenever you need/want to get a binary outcome from from a continuous output score.

So if you have problems with anomalies going undetected because they are under your threshold, then you must do either or both of the following:

- Improve your selection of threshold value
- Improve your anomaly scoring model